# Entity Framework cast selected fields to varchar and concat them

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I want do below query in Entity Framework

```
select 
    cast(p_min as varchar) + '' + cast(p_max as varchar)  
from 
    user_behave_fact
where 
    beef_dairy_stat = 'True' and param_id = 2
group by 
    p_min,p_max
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned a language, I am writing code in C#.

Try this:

```
using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
   var output = (
                 from fact in dbContext.user_behave_facts
                 where fact.beef_dairy_stat == "True" && fact.param_id == 2
                 group fact by new {fact.p_min, fact.p_max} in grp
                 select new
                 {
                    ColName = grp.Key.p_min.ToString() + " " + grp.Key.p_max.ToString()
                 }
                 ).ToList();
}
```

`.ToList()` can be changed according to your expectations

Comment: @RouzbehZarandi, may be ask a separate question with your specific issue. This will help you and others. If you still want me to convert this only, let me know

Comment: thank you @sunil for attention ... i opened a question section and i got the answer ...hope it will help others like me